# Snowflake flatten json SQL

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause

I have a list of a lot of product IDs saved in a `.csv` file.

I need to query Snowflake for the product IDs, where each product ID is couched inside a JSON object in a field called PRODUCTCODES. Each value in PRODUCT CODES is included in an array, so there can be multiple product codes for a single record and ROWID.

Example:

```
[
    { "type": "product_id", "value": "BRB580900062" } 
]
```

Or:

```
[
    { "type": "product_id", "value": "BRB580900062" } ,
    { "type": "product_id", "value": "G2G102341235" }
]
```

I have written this script to pull the records for one product ID at a time, like this:

```
select ROWID, PRODUCTCODES, DESCRIPTORS
from PRODUCTTABLE
where PRODUCTCODES like '%BRB580900062%'
```

However, this is of course only one row at a time - I need the script to pull the rows for all of the 1 million product IDs in my file.

Is there a function which will allow me to do this? And is there anything about the code I have currently written that could be written in a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show how the multiple values are stored in JSON?  It appears you are trying to evaluate `PRODUCTCODES` as a string, where if you queried it as a VARIANT, you wouldn't need to use a `LIKE`.  Is each value a separate row in the table or are the values in an array inside a single record?

Comment: Each value is in an array inside a single record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the flatten to extract the productId for each row and then you can easily apply whatever filter you want on that.

Below script will create dedicated column for productId to enable filtering.

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

```
with PRODUCTTABLE as (
select 1 ROWID,'DESCRIPTORS1' DESCRIPTORS,
parse_json('[
    { "type": "product_id", "value": "BRB580900062" } 
]') PRODUCTCODES
union

select 2 ROWID,'DESCRIPTORS2' DESCRIPTORS,
parse_json('[
    { "type": "product_id", "value": "BRB580900062" } 
    ,{ "type": "product_id", "value": "G2G102341235" } 
]') PRODUCTCODES

)
select rowId,DESCRIPTORS,f.value:"value"::varchar product_id, PRODUCTCODES
from PRODUCTTABLE a
,lateral flatten(a.PRODUCTCODES) f
where product_id in ('BRB580900062');
```